# Failed to create Console with embed VFS due to "Call to a possibly undefined method"

Tags: actionscript-3, alchemy, flascc

First I've created an embedded Virtual File System, as described [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/flascc/docs/Reference.html#section_vfs).

It generates this AS code:

```
package C_Run {}
package com.adobe.flascc.vfs {

    import com.adobe.flascc.vfs.*;
    import com.adobe.flascc.BinaryData

    public class myvfs extends InMemoryBackingStore {

        public function myvfs() {
            addDirectory("/data")
            addFile("/data/localization.en.afgpack", new     C_Run.ALC_FS_6D79766673202F646174612F6C6F63616C697A6174696F6E2E656E2E6166677061636B)
            addFile("/data/dataAudio.afgpack", new     C_Run.ALC_FS_6D79766673202F646174612F64617461417564696F2E6166677061636B)
            addFile("/data/data.afgpack", new     C_Run.ALC_FS_6D79766673202F646174612F646174612E6166677061636B)
        }    
    }
}
```

It is compiled into `myvfs.abc`.
Then I'm trying to create custom console with this VFS.
I've imported `myvfs` in `Console.as`:

```
import com.adobe.flascc.vfs.myvfs;
```

And created vfs object:

```
var my_vfs_embedded:InMemoryBackingStore = new myvfs();
```

So, the problem is that compiling `Console.abc` sometimes fails with error "`Call to a possibly undefined method myvfs`" and sometimes builds successfully with the same code. How can this be?

`Console.abc` is built by this command:

```
cd ./../../Engine/library/baselib/sources/flash &&  \
     java -jar $(FLASCC_FOR_EXT)/usr/lib/asc2.jar -merge -md -AS3 -strict -optimize \
    -import $(FLASCC_FOR_EXT)/usr/lib/builtin.abc \
    -import $(FLASCC_FOR_EXT)/usr/lib/playerglobal.abc \
    -import $(GLS3D_ABS)/install/usr/lib/libGL.abc \
    -import $(FLASCC_FOR_EXT)/usr/lib/ISpecialFile.abc \
    -import $(FLASCC_FOR_EXT)/usr/lib/IBackingStore.abc \
    -import $(FLASCC_FOR_EXT)/usr/lib/IVFS.abc \
    -import $(FLASCC_FOR_EXT)/usr/lib/InMemoryBackingStore.abc \
    -import $(FLASCC_FOR_EXT)/usr/lib/AlcVFSZip.abc \
    -import $(FLASCC_FOR_EXT)/usr/lib/CModule.abc \
    -import $(FLASCC_FOR_EXT)/usr/lib/C_Run.abc \
    -import $(FLASCC_FOR_EXT)/usr/lib/BinaryData.abc \
    -import $(FLASCC_FOR_EXT)/usr/lib/PlayerKernel.abc \
    -import $(BUILD_FULL_PATH)/myvfs.abc \
    Console.as -outdir $(BUILD_FULL_PATH) -out Console
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like my VFS was too big for compiler. When I take less data everything was ok. So, I suppose it was a bug in compiler.

Answer (score 0):

myvfs.abc is located at BUILD_FULL_PATH, hinting that it might be built at the same time as Console.as. If the build order is not fully predictable, the myvfs.abc binary might be in an undetermined state when Console.as is compiled. This can happen if, for instance, you build myvfs.as and Console.as as different independent targets and are using multithreaded option in make (-j).

Comment: -j option for make not used